# como usar $(this) + checked?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<input type="radio" name="teste1" value="SIM"> TESTE 1
<input type="radio" name="teste1" value="NÃO"> TESTE 2



$(document).ready(function(){
    $("[name='teste1']").click(function () {
        var teste = $(this+":checked").val();
        alert(teste);

    });
});
```

Como pegar o valor usando $(this) + checked?

```
    if($("[name='teste1']").is(":checked")){
        var teste = $(this+":checked").val();
        alert(teste);
    }
```

está dando erro:
http://jsfiddle.net/hv2wc25v/

Gostaria de saber como poderia utilizar o seletor `:checked` , quando o `this` já é o seletor.

Comment: @Wallace, como é radio apenas um elemento será o selecionado, portanto não há necessidade de verificar qual deles esta  checked, pelo fato de você já definir que no click o this ficará setado. sendo assim apenas $(this).val(); resolveria o seu problema, ou você poderia me mostrar um caso que não resolveria?

Comment: @GabrielRodrigues, está certinho. Talvez em casos bem específicos venha dar problemas, mas veja minha resposta, por exemplo, que fiz utilizando apenas o `this`, como você demonstrou. Porém estou usando o método `change`, e não o `click`. Creio que seja mais apropriado

Comment: Se você quisesse acionar uma função toda vez que alguem mudasse o radio change seria a melhor opção, até por que no click se você continuar a clicar no mesmo radio ja checkado ele continuaria a disparar a função.

Comment: Denali, alguma resposta resolve o teu problema? É interessante você dar um feedback, pois outra pessoa pode ter o mesmo problema, e ao chegar aqui saberá o que foi feito. :) Veja [aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) o que você pode fazer ao obter uma resposta para sua pergunta. ;)

Answer (score 6):

Existe também outra forma, que é utilizando a função `filter`.

Assim:

```js
 $(function (){
      
      $("[name='teste1']").click(function () {
         alert($(this).filter(':checked').val());
      });
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="teste1" value="SIM"> TESTE 1
<input type="radio" name="teste1" value="NÃO"> TESTE 2
```

O primeiro caso pode caber muito bem, mas você ainda pode fazer utilizando a função `change`, já que `this` se trata do elemento atual no qual foi disparado o evento.

Use a função `change`:

```
 $(function (){

      $("[name='teste1']").change(function () {
         alert($(this).val());
      });
    })
```

**Nota:** Com change, só será disparado quando houver alternância entre os valores. Ou seja, clicar em um checkbox já marcado, não haverá atividades capturada por `change`.

Answer (score 5):

Tenta assim:

```
$(this).is(":checked")
```

Algo que também gosto de fazer, particularmente, é atribuir tudo em variávies, assim:

```
var $myRadio = $("#idDoRadio");

$myRadio.on('click', function () {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
          alert($(this).val())
    }
});
```

Comment: $(this).is(":checked").val()
queria pegar o valor, parece que não deu certo.

Comment: Verifica se dessa forma resolve: http://jsfiddle.net/hv2wc25v/2/

Comment: Acho que a resposta do @Wallace resolve.

Comment: Vamos lá. Observando bem a resposta, `is(':checked')` não retorna o objeto jQuery. e sim, `boolean`. Para fazer o que ele está precisando, vou ter que editar a resposta.

Comment: Sim, no início ele não tinha descrito que precisava obter o valor do radio checado (ou eu não prestei atenção), da maneira que expliquei serve apenas para validar se está ou não checado. Mas após verificar é possível acessar o valor utilizando $(this).val()